# In Android change a Method from Void to Return?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a game in which I'm drawing a path that starts at the center x,y coordinates of a `RelativeLayout`. I'm getting the x,y coordinates, but I can't figure out how to pass the coordinates into the Path Drawing Class using my `getNumbers()` method. I've got this bit in the `onCreate`:

```
getNumbers();
path_em = new PathEM(this, xTint, yTint);
gBoard_RL.addView(path_em);
root_RL.addView(gBoard_RL);
```

and here's `getNumbers()`:

```
    public void getNumbers() {
    gBoard_RL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(NumbersoGLL);
}
OnGlobalLayoutListener NumbersoGLL = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        xRLWInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth() / 2;
        yRLHInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight() / 2;
        xTint = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xRLWInt;
        yTint = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yRLHInt;   
    }
};
```

I think I have to rewrite getNumbers() so that's it's not void, but returns xTint and yTint, right? I don't know how to do that because `public void onGlobalLayout()` can't be changed to pass an int, when I try I get an error saying that it HAS to be void.

So basically, what I'm trying to do is in the `onCreate` of `Game3` Class I need to get the center coordinate integers, then pass them into my Path Drawing Class. Here's the entire Game 3 Class:

```
public class Game3 extends Activity {
PathEM path_em;
RelativeLayout root_RL, gBoard_RL, startTimer_RL;
LayoutParams root_LP, startTimer_LP, gBoardInfo_LP, gBoard_LP, rootStartTimer_LP;
LayoutInflater LayInf = null;
View root_VUE, gBoardInfo_VUE;
TextView gameScore_TV, gameTime_TV, readyCD_TV;
FrameLayout root_FrameL;
int xScrInt, yScrInt, xRLWInt, yRLHInt, xTint, yTint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.cutin, R.anim.cutout);


    // -- Create Root Layout
    root_RL = new RelativeLayout(this);
    root_LP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    root_RL.setId(1);
    root_RL.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    root_RL.setLayoutParams(root_LP);
    // --- END Create Root Layout

    // --- Create GameBoard
    LayInf = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    gBoardInfo_VUE = LayInf.inflate(R.layout.game1_info, null);
    gBoardInfo_LP = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    gBoardInfo_LP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,
            RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    gBoardInfo_VUE.setId(2);
    gBoardInfo_VUE.setLayoutParams(gBoardInfo_LP);
    gameTime_TV = (TextView) gBoardInfo_VUE
            .findViewById(R.id.game1_timeValue2_TV);
    gameScore_TV = (TextView) gBoardInfo_VUE
            .findViewById(R.id.game1_scoreValue2_TV);
    root_RL.addView(gBoardInfo_VUE);

    gBoard_RL = new RelativeLayout(this);
    gBoard_LP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    gBoard_LP.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, gBoardInfo_VUE.getId());
    gBoard_LP.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    gBoard_RL.setLayoutParams(gBoard_LP);
    gBoard_RL.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    //--- add stuff here
    getNumbers();
    path_em = new PathEM(this, xTint, yTint);
    gBoard_RL.addView(path_em);
    root_RL.addView(gBoard_RL);

    root_FrameL = new FrameLayout(this);
    root_FrameL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    root_FrameL.addView(root_RL);
    setContentView(root_FrameL);
    // --- END Create GameBoard

}//--- END onCreate


public void getNumbers() {
    gBoard_RL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(NumbersoGLL);
}
OnGlobalLayoutListener NumbersoGLL = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        xRLWInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth() / 2;
        yRLHInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight() / 2;
        xTint = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xRLWInt;
        yTint = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yRLHInt;   
    }
};


//--- PathEM Class
public class PathEM extends View {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Path path = new Path();

    public PathEM(Context context, int xTint, int yTint){
        super(context);
    }

    Pt[] thePath = { new Pt(xTint, yTint),
            new Pt(200, 200),
            new Pt(200, 500),
            new Pt(400, 500)
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        path.moveTo(thePath[0].x, thePath[0].y);
        for (int i = 1; i < thePath.length; i++) {
            path.lineTo(thePath[i].x, thePath[i].y);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }// --- END onDraw

    class Pt {
        float x, y;

        Pt(float _x, float _y) {
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the code where you initialize the `PathEM` object in the `onGlobalLayout()` Method.
Like this:

```
OnGlobalLayoutListener NumbersoGLL = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {

    xRLWInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth() / 2;
    yRLHInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight() / 2;
    xTint = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xRLWInt;
    yTint = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yRLHInt;   

    path_em = new PathEM(this, xTint, yTint);
    gBoard_RL.addView(path_em);
    root_RL.addView(gBoard_RL);
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks `@Sherif EINady`, I think your solution is the correct way to go, but running the app, I get a blank screen because the content view is being created in the method, not in `onCreate`. So I need to figure out how to add the views not in the method, but in `onCreate`.

Comment: You should leave setContentView(root_FrameL) in the onCreate() method as it was.

Comment: Your solution works with one modification: change the context from `this` to `getApplicationContext()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a Constants Class and setting the variable of contants variable in your onGlobalLayout() method.

That way you need not do any return.

```
public class Constants {

public static int value1=0;
public static int value2=0;
public static int value3=0;
public static int value4=0;

}
```

In your onGlobalLayout() method

```
Constants.value1= gBoard_RL.getWidth() / 2;
        Constants.value2= gBoard_RL.getHeight() / 2;
        Constants.value3= gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xRLWInt;
        Constants.value4= gBoard_RL.getTop() + yRLHInt;
```